# Image not displaying for google plus button with regards to the snippet

Tags: google-plus-one

I am trying to determine why an image I am wanting to use for the google plus button snippet.  I am using an open graph meta tag to provide the url for the image.  I have also made the image currently to be at 120x120.   The only thing I am not sure about is that it is a .png image, instead of a .jpg or .gif.   I could not find anything on the google forums or on the developers information, that a .png wouldn't work, but I am at a loss for what the problem is.  I know that the snippet for the button is grabbing the information for the title and description from the open graph mark up, but for whatever it is ignoring the image, and just using random images from the site.

**UPDATE, I was able to determine my problem, the open graph meta tags were not formatted correctly, i needed to have meta property and i had meta name, in case anybody wanted to know**